# Ionic 4 - AuthGuard page routing permission delayed

Tags: angular, typescript, authentication, ionic-framework

I have an ionic 4 app that is storing information about the user natively. When the user opens the app then if his information is there then I want him to be sent to the Home Page. If he is not then I want him to be routed to the Login Page, pretty normal.

The problem that I am running into is that for about 500ms you will see the Login Page and then upon reading the information *then* it will redirect you to the home page.

What I would like is for the application to *WAIT* On the response from the storage *before* it directs you to the Login Page or the Home Page.

#### App.component.ts

```js
  public initializeApp(): void {
    this.platform.ready().then((): void => {
      this.statusBar.styleDefault();
      this.splashScreen.hide();
      this.authService.authState.subscribe((state: boolean): void => {
        if (state) {
          this.router.navigate(['home']);
        } else {
          this.router.navigate(['login-register']);
        }
      });
      this.permissionService.requestCameraPermission();
    });
  }
```

#### AuthService.service.ts

```js
public readonly authState: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false)

  private _ifLoggedIn(): void {
    // just sees if his info is saved, if so then he has been logged in
    this.userService.getUserInfo().then((response: UserData): void => {
      if (response) {
        this.authState.next(true);
      }
    });
  }

  public isAuthenticated(): boolean {
    return this.authState.value;
  }
```

#### AuthGuard

```js
export class AuthGuardService {
  private authService: AuthService;

  public constructor(authService: AuthService) {
    this.authService = authService;
  }
  public canActivate(): boolean {
    return this.authService.isAuthenticated();
  }
}
```

#### app-routing.module.ts

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'login-register',
    pathMatch: 'full',
  },
  {
    path: 'login-register',
    loadChildren: () => import('../pages/login-register/login-register.module').then(m => m.LoginRegisterPageModule),
  },
  {
    path: 'home',
    loadChildren: () => import('../pages/home/home.module').then(m => m.HomePageModule),
    canActivate: [AuthGuardService],
  },
];
```

if there is anything other information you need let me know. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first problem that you have is `BehaviorSubject` got initialized so it will return a result directly when you ask for a result.

The second problem is that `isAuthenticated()` will return the value because it is sync method, but you need anybody who calls it to wait.

The solution is to use `ReplySubject` and make `isAuthenticated()` async.

**AuthService.service.ts**

```
public readonly authState: ReplaySubject<boolean> = new ReplaySubject<boolean>(1)

  private _ifLoggedIn(): void {
    // just sees if his info is saved, if so then he has been logged in
    this.userService.getUserInfo().then((response: UserData): void => {
        this.authState.next(!!response);
    }, (reason) => this.authState.next(false));
  }

  public async isAuthenticated(): Promise<boolean> {
    return this.authState.asObservable().pipe(take(1)).toPromise();
  }
```

Note that `this.authState.next(false)` is to return a result and not stuck forever waiting, so if error returned like error 401, it will consider it not logged in.

And `this.authState.next(!!response)` is just shorten format for your previous condition, and will handle the case if response returned with `null` or `undefined` if you implemented your `.getUserInfo()` like that the user is not logged in.

**AuthGuard**

```
export class AuthGuardService implements CanActivate {
  private authService: AuthService;

  public constructor(authService: AuthService) {
    this.authService = authService;
  }
  public async canActivate(): Promise<boolean> {
    return this.authService.isAuthenticated();
  }
}
```

Note that `canActivate()` support async implementation already, also, I added `implements CanActivate` so it does make more sense.

You can learn more about the types of `Subject` here: [Understanding rxjs BehaviorSubject, ReplaySubject and AsyncSubject](https://medium.com/@luukgruijs/understanding-rxjs-behaviorsubject-replaysubject-and-asyncsubject-8cc061f1cfc0)

Comment: I'm not sure how you implemented `this.userService.getUserInfo()` but if you do return `null` or `undefined` if the user is not logged in, OR in case you return the error, in both cases, the code above will work.

Comment: right the code works like a charm! thanks so much! Right I have conditions already for null or undefined responses, thanks a lot for your help! also thank you for posting an article about them. It's always tough with all the various methods on observables and different types of observables